# EF Core database configuration

Tags: c#, mysql, database, wpf, ef-core-3.1

Hi I'm needing a little help with EF CORE in WPF I'm still new to ef core, I'm getting duplicate entry with primary key when adding a job, I'm assuming its trying to insert the same contact and department into the tables where I'm currently storing them.

Error when adding a job is
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: 'An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.'

Inner exception
MySqlException: Duplicate entry '4' for key 'PRIMARY'

all values passed to the add job command have the correct values

code is

```
public static class JobsService
{
    public static async Task<List<Job>> GetJobs()
    {
        using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();

            return await db.Jobs.ToListAsync();
        }
    }

    public static async Task AddJob(string title, string partNumber, double quantity, Contact assignedTo, Department department)
    {
        using(var db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            db.Database.EnsureCreated();

            var job = new Job(title, partNumber, quantity, assignedTo, department);
            await db.Jobs.AddAsync(job);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}

public class Job
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
    public double? ReceivedQuantity { get; set; }
    public string PartNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Contact AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public Contact? CompletedBy { get; set; }

    public DateTimeOffset? CompletedDateTime { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
    public JobStatus Status { get; set; }

    public Job(string title, string partNumber, double quantity, Contact assignedTo, Department department)
    {
        Title = title;
        PartNumber = partNumber;
        Quantity = quantity;
        AssignedTo = assignedTo;
        Department = department;
        CreatedBy = UsersService.LoggedInUser;
        CreatedDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
    }

    public Job()
    {

    } 
}

 public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ContactType Type { get; set; }
    public Title Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string TelephoneNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? DeletedDateTime { get; internal set; }
    public string FullName { get; private set; }
    public Address? Address { get; set; }

    public Contact(ContactType type, Title title, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, string telephoneNumber)
    {
        Type = type;
        Title = Title;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        EmailAddress = emailAddress;
        TelephoneNumber = telephoneNumber;
        IsDeleted = false;
        Address = new Address();
    }

    public Contact()
    {

    }

    public void AddAddress(string line1, string line2, string line3, string city, string county, string postCode, Country country)
    {
        Address = new Address(line1, line2, line3, city, county, postCode, country);
    }

    public void Update(ContactType type, Title title, string firstName, string lastName, string emailAddress, string telephoneNumber)
    {
        Type = type;
        Title = title;
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
        EmailAddress = emailAddress;
        TelephoneNumber = telephoneNumber;
    }

    public void Update(Contact contact)
    {
        Type = contact.Type;
        Title = contact.Title;
        FirstName = contact.FirstName;
        LastName = contact.LastName;
        EmailAddress = contact.EmailAddress;
        TelephoneNumber = contact.TelephoneNumber;
        Address = contact.Address;
    }

    public void Delete()
    {
        if(IsDeleted)
        {
            return;
        }

        IsDeleted = true;
        DeletedDateTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow;
    }

    public void Restore()
    {
        IsDeleted = false;
        DeletedDateTime = null;
    }
}

public class ContactEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Contact>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Contact> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(x => x.FullName)
            .HasComputedColumnSql($"CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName)");
    }
}

public class Department
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Department()
    {

    }

    public Department(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

public class DepartmentEntityTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Department>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Department> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
    }
}

class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{

    public DbSet<Item> Inventory { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tags> ItemTags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TaggedItems> TaggedItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SavedDirectory> Directorys { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        var settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;

        if (settings != null)
        {
            foreach (ConnectionStringSettings cs in settings)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseMySQL(cs.ConnectionString);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
   

        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.PartNumber);  
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Permission>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<CloudAccount>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Tags>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
            entity.HasMany(e => e.CloudAccounts);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<SavedDirectory>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Job>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Country>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
        });

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new ContactEntityTypeConfiguration());
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new DepartmentEntityTypeConfiguration());
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The contract constructor is putting a zero in for the Id which is causing the duplicate key.

Comment: Are you sure that the SqlUpdateException is related to the Job table? Could you please send exception details?

Comment: You don't need the fluent haskey as well as key attribute. I don't know offhand what effect having both would give. Try adding [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] as well as [key]

Comment: Hi exception details screenshotted in post now

Comment: Hi I'm still getting the same error with [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] as well as [key]

Comment: Hey I figured it now now, I needed to store the Id's instead of Contact and Department objects and use a virtual object instead, then include them when getting the list of jobs

Answer (score 0):

This occurs due to update in the database model please goto edmx file and import your database model again to it. this will help you. but if still you facing the same issue then Truncate your previous data in database and import the model again to configure the injectors. then run hope that will fix your error.